# Recursion in Error Handling?

Tags: java, exception, recursion

I'm writing a file reader that returns an object and I'd like it to warn on parse errors and continue to the next record.

The code below is the obvious implementation of this, but involves recursing from inside the catch block.  Is there any technical or stylistic reason not to do this?

```
public RecordType nextRecord() throws IOException{
    if (reader == null){
        throw new IllegalStateException("Reader closed.");
    }
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if (line == null){
        return null;
    }else{
        try {
            return parseRecord(line);
        }catch (ParseException pex){
            logger.warn("Record ignored due to parse error: " 
                + pex.getMessage());
            //Note the recursion here
            return nextRecord();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that your program will accumulate stack space with each erronous record, which makes it vulnerable. When this piece of code would be part of a web service, for example, an attacker could feed just many many error records until the whole service dies from a stack overflow. This would be a successful denial of service attack.

Comment: @Ingo thanks, that should be an answer :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer to use a loop.  With recursion, you never know how deep you can safely go.

```
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    try {
        return parseRecord(line);
    }catch (ParseException pex){
        logger.warn("Record ignored due to parse error: " + pex);
    }
}
return null;
```

Comment: Yeah, and debugging that StackOverflowError would be a pain wouldn't it?

Comment: You would see a lot of warnings before the error at least. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not replace the recursion with a loop:

```
public RecordType nextRecord() throws IOException {
    if (reader == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Reader closed.");
    }
    for (;;) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            try {
                return parseRecord(line);
            } catch (ParseException pex) {
                logger.warn("Record ignored due to parse error: "
                        + pex.getMessage());
                // continue to the next record
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Stylistically, I find this preferable.

Comment: It's slightly less clear (arguable), and you didn't answer the question: Is there any reason *not* to use recursion.

Comment: @C. Ross: The last sentence is my (subjective) argument for why I consider this preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be cleaner to let the ParseException propagate back to the caller? The caller could then decide what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

What it seems like to me is that whatever is calling your method is going to keep calling it until the method returns null.

I would probably follow the advice of the previous posters and use a loop, however I would look at whatever is calling the method (as it is probably already using a loop), have it skip the line by looking for an exception to be thrown.